# “Is there a matlab function for dividing matrices into specify blocks given by user?

Tags: matlab, divide

I have large in size  matrix(n* n) and i want to divide it by n*a dimension blocks where a is given by user in matlab

`matrix=hadamard(64);`

Comment: What if `a/n` is not an integer? How do you want to store these blocks?

Comment: The input is integer

Comment: So you want to reshape your matrix into an `n x a x n/a` 3D matrix?

Comment: yes into a n *a

Comment: @theNewArtist That doesn't really answer the question. Do you want a single `n x a ` array? Do you want multiple `n x a` arrays? Do you want a 3-dimensional array containing all of the elements of the original array? What exactly is your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB has a build-in [reshape](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) function doing exactly what you want:

```matlab
n = size(matrix, 1);
res = reshape(matrix, n, a, []);
```

The result is a `n x a x n/a` matrix `res`.

**Update:** As *@Adriaan* correctly pointed out in comments, introducing an additional dimension is not the only way to split two dimensional matrix into several smaller ones. The same result could be achieved with [Cell Arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) and [mat2cell](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) build-in function:

```
res2 = mat2cell(matrix, [n], repmat(a, 1, n/a));
```

Comment: This is incorrect, as it would, as the function name suggests, *reshape* the entire matrix, as opposed to cutting it up in blocks, which is what the OP wants.

Comment: There are two ways to "cut up" a matrix: to introduce an additional dimension or to use a cell array.

Comment: Though you're right that I should've mentioned [mat2cell](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) solution as well.